# Run interpreted commands within sudo

Tags: command-line, bash, python, sudo

The question is how to run generic commands which may contain ; && | <  > << >> $ and so on within sudo.

Possible solutions could be:

1. To use interpreters within sudo

`sudo /bin/bash -c 'command ; command | ...'`

or

`sudo -s <<< 'command ; command | ...'`

But I don't have sudoer /bin/bash /bin/sh or any other permissions. So that gets me permission denied.

2. I could also use something like this:

`sudo command ; sudo command`

But the problem is that i need a solution working for any command given as an argument to my function (see context)

Some context:

I'm writing a python Popen wrapper which has a flag sudo=True/False. If sudo is true It should run any given command string within sudo (meaning the commands can contain ;| <> &&)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps writing the commands to a shell script, making it executable and running it with sudo will do what you need.

However what you are doing is very dangerous. Allowing potentially untrusted command line to be executed as a root is a disaster waiting to happen. Look up "shell injection" type of vulnerabilities. Then perhaps consider reviewing what needs to be done and then redesigning it without the need to run any command as sudo.

Comment: I don't have sudo permissions, to run any new script.